# Bash "coalesce" functionality

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do the following on a single line:

```
if [ -z "$foo" ]
then
    source "$foo/subdir/yo.sh"
else
    source "$bar/yo.sh"
fi
```

(note the subdir only present if foo is used). The simplest solution so far is:

```
source "${foo:-$bar}${foo:+/subdir}/yo.sh"
```

In other words, take either foo or bar, then append `/subdir` if foo exists. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: The latter seems obfuscated to me. Why do you want to have it on a single line when a well-constructed test with `if` ... `fi` is more readable? Being short is OK as long as it is still understandable

Comment: The problem is that both solutions duplicate code - There should be some way to mention "source", "foo", and "/yo.sh" only once.

Comment: The only other forms I can think of are `[ -z "$foo" ] && source "$foo/subdir/yo.sh" || "$bar/yo.sh"` or something really ugly like `dest="$foo/subdir/yo.sh"; source ${dest/#\/subdir/$bar}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$((printf $foo 2>/dev/null && printf '/subdir') || printf $bar)/yo.sh
```

Kind of convoluted though.

The key aspect to this solution is finding a way to both output the contents of $foo, if any, and simultaneously branch based on whether something was in $foo. printf with no arguments is an error and $foo with no contents results in no arguments to printf. After that the rest is easy.

For this reason the first `printf` needs to be printf but the others could be replaced with `echo -n` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
amithere=$foo   
if [ ! -z "$amithere" ]   
then    
    amithere=$bar    
fi    
source "$amithere/yo.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ -d $foo ]]; then
    dir="$foo/subdir"
else
    dir="$bar"
fi
source "$dir/yo.sh"
```